# Rsync copy remote hardlinks not entire file

Tags: rsync

I have some incremental backups on my cPanel server where backups taken store one directory and others backups have hardlinks to files. How can I download this hardlinks instead of entire files?

/backup is the main backup directory

/backup/1 is where files are stored

/backup/2 is where new files are stored and files that exists in /1 are hard links.
Now i need to download hardlinks as harlinks not as complete files, how can i do that with rsync?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The -H option for rsync copies hard links.

But remember that if these hard links are absolute (i.e., start with /), then they may not point to the right destinations.  Hard/symlinks should be relative (i.e., start with .. or a subdir) if you want to rsync them to different locations.

Comment: This problem does not exist with hard links, because of the way hard links work.